# Projection to create a grid in km

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grids-graticules

I am trying to create a 1km2 grid of Kenya but I'm struggling. I have changed the projection to EPSG:32337 but this makes Kenya about 10 metres long which is obviously not right and leads to an error that the area I want to grid is too large. The standard projection (WGS84) will only allow me to create a grid in degrees.

Comment: Please describe the grid creation process more detailled.

Comment: Using 'create grid' in vector research tools, selecting my Kenya shapefile as the extent using the same projection as the layer and project (EPSG: 32337). Horizontal and Vertical spacing both set to 1km and both overlays left at zero. This brings up an error message stating:"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\Grid.py", line 133, in processAlgorithm
self.tr('Horizontal spacing is too large for the covered area'))
_core.QgsProcessingException: Horizontal spacing is too large for the covered area"

Comment: Do not use "set crs". Reproject your data properly by using "export as" and set the crs there

Comment: Following up on @MrXsquared's suggestion, before reprojecting your data, return it to the original CRS. If you reproject data whose CRS you changed, it will be even more wrong once re-projected.